# Como bloquear acesso a uma aplicação pelo IP do usuário?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Como faço para bloquear o acesso a uma aplicação java web pelo IP do usuário.

A aplicação será hospedada fora do ambiente da empresa, mas preciso que por determinado perfil possa ser acessado de fora.

Eu tenho no cadastro de usuários o perfil de cada um e pensei que ao tentar logar eu pudesse de alguma forma validar se ele está dentro da empresa ou não.

Como fazer?

Comment: Talvez vc precise ver um pouco mais sobre redes, se sua empresa utiliza a internet ou uma intranet ( onde vc poderia ter um mapeamento de todos os IPs "estático " ) , ou criar uma tabela ou um xml com os IPs que possam acessar. Bom ai vc tem que ver a melhor forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar o IP do usuário assim:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
```

E em seu cadastro de usuário/privilégios, inserir uma opção de `Acesso Externo`.

Ao realizar o login, você compara se o IP do usuário está no range de IPs pré-definidos da empresa (isso se ela tiver IP fixo), caso a condição for falsa, verifica se ele possui acesso externo.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de mais tem de certificar que o utilizador registado com permissão para aceder do exterior utiliza um ip estático (caso contrario pode usar software para ajudar nesse ponto).

Uma das alternativas utilizando .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /specific_page.html
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 111.222.333.444
```

Comment: O problema é que desta forma eu bloqueio todos os acessos, mas preciso que alguns usuários possam acessar a aplicação externamente.

Comment: No allow define os ips que permite que acedam

Comment: Entendi, o problema é que apenas alguns usuários terão acesso externo e não tenho como saber qual IP vai utilizar. Dentro da empresa existe um faixa específica de IP e acho que terei que limitar desta forma, ou seja, se estiver fora do IP da empresa, apenas os gerentes podem acessar. Os funcionários não.

Comment: I understand, the problem is that only some users will have external access and have no way of knowing which IP will use. Within the company there is a specific range of IP and I think we have to limit this way, ie if you are outside the company's IP, only managers can access. Employees do not.

Comment: Então como quer validar se o ip esta autorizado ou nao? Para conseguir fazer isso tem de saber de ante-mao o ip atribuido ao utilizador (Static IP)

Comment: Acredito que a empresa tenha um range de IP. Então é possível fazer assim tendo o range de IPs, certo?

Comment: Pelo range de ips é possivel, pois acaba por saber quais os que estao dentro daquele range. Mas tambem pode significar que nem todos que pertencem a range de ips irao ter acesso apartir do exterior

Comment: Senão de que outra forma identifica os utilizadores da sua empresa? Pelo que percebi esta a falar de ips externos!